# Git Release Branch Closeout Procedure to Verify Without Merging

Tags: git, release-management

How do you ensure that all changes on a release branch also exist on the mainline branch (master in this case)?

Ideally, we all have continuous deployment and never need release branches.  If we do need them, we need to know how check if all required changes made to a release branch made it back to mainline (master in this case).

When we create the release branch we:

- Create release branch `git checkout master -b release/0.0`
- Note origin point `git log -n 1`
- make changes on master and `cherry-pick -x`
- some problems require PR or direct change on release branch
- we may not want all of those changes to be merged back to master branch

At the end we have some changes which trace their provenance back to master and some which don't.  Given, we may not want the entire set back on master, merge isn't an option.

We need a way for the team to review changes to ensure we have all required changes back on master.  Especially if we had bugfix or hotfix branches off of the release branch.

If we use diff or run a test merge we see all the churn on the release branch and may see changes made to master for the next release should we be in concurrent development mode.

On way to reduce the noise and focus on actual changes needing cherry-pick back to master would be this approach:

- create a squash-branch from release branch origin `git checkout <release-branch-origin-commit-id> -b squash-release-0.0`
- squash all changes on release branch into a single commit `git merge --squash release/0.0`
- commit those changes as a single commit
- create a closeout-validation branch from master `git checkout master -b closout-release-0.0`
- cherry pick change without commit `git cherry-pick --no-commit <squashbranch single commit sha>`
- review the diffs and conflicts

When we do this we find any back and forth with reverts is smoothed out and the diffs / conflicts are of a small number of files.  We still must look up the files and check annotation to determine correct course of action but we do so with a much smaller range.

If you do need to use long standing release branches or maintenance branches, how do you ensure that changes which should propagate to master and future release do so?

Comment: Perhaps not very helpful to say this, but it sounds like the issue here is the workflow - a combination of long-lived branches plus changes that you don't want to merge back.  Are the latter so common/large that you couldn't solve the problem with a revert and then a merge?

Comment: Oh, so we'd make a temporary branch, revert the content we don't want and then merge back to master?  Interesting.  That might be a simpler approach.

Comment: Indeed, that's basically what I was imagining.  Depending on the ratio of "changes we want to keep" vs. "changes we want to discard", it might be significantly less complex to do it this way round (as well as more explicit in the commit history).

Answer (score 0):

The best option seems to be - avoid the problem entirely by only ever cherry-picking to release branches.  If this isn't possible, then the squashbranch approach seems to work reasonably well

```
repo=$1
relBranch=$2
branchStart=$3

workDir=${repo}-closeout-`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`

git clone .../${repo}.git ${workDir}

pushd ${workDir}
# update release branch
git checkout ${relBranch}; git pull

# create branch from branch start
git checkout ${branchStart} -b squash/${relBranch}

# Squash Merge branch history into single commit
git clean -d -f -x .
git merge --squash ${relBranch}

# check that status reports only staged changes
git commit -m "release/0.9 squash ${branchStart}..HEAD"
squashedCommit=`git log --format="%H" -n 1`

# Prepare master
git checkout master; git pull

# create staging branch for delta check
git checkout -b deltacheck/${relBranch}
git clean -d -f -x .

# check release branch history delta
git cherry-pick --no-commit ${squashedCommit}

git status

# Diff 
git diff
popd
```